# Can I get a day and a month in DD MM formats from Luxon library?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, luxon

Now I can get a day and a month in format 7/6/2019. But I need something like this 07/06/2019. For now, I didn't find a method which returns me a day/month in my desirable format.

Comment: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html#table-of-tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html), consider the following:

```js
console.log(luxon.DateTime.local().toFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')); //07/06/2019
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.17.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```